# MS SQL - Sequential read and write

Tags: sql-server, sequential

I have filtered into a table the data I need, but realized it is on 3 different rows.

I need help coding logic in MS SQL to accomplish the following. Basically, the data I need is on 3 different rows. All of the data is needed from the "W" row and only the data in the DESC column from the next 2 rows, which will also have the same date and time.

1. Read TABLE A sequentially
2. If Column AC contains "W" saving the data.
3. Read next row, save data in the DESC column.
4. Read next row, save data in the DESC
5. Write the data into TABLE B.
6. Read until next Column AC contains "W, repeat 2-5
7. End

TABLE A

```
DATE    TIME ACCT ATM AC AMT LOCATION
7/11/16 1040 5555     C   0  DUNKIN #3          
7/11/16 1105 5555 #1  W  -20                                                
7/11/16 1105 5555     C   0  ATM                
7/11/16 1105 5555     C   0  DUNKIN #3  
7/12/16 2141 5555     C   0  BP#9   
7/19/16 1025 5555 #2  W  -40                                            
7/19/16 1025 5555     C   0  ATM                
7/19/16 1025 5555     C   0  SBUCKS #1  
7/21/16 2102 5555     C   0  BP#5
```

TABLE B

```
DATE    TIME ACCT ATM AC AMT TRAN LOCATION
7/11/16 1105 5555 #1  W  -20 ATM  DUNKIN #3
7/19/16 1025 5555 #2  W  -40 ATM  STARBUCKS #1
```

Comment: First and most importantly.. you need to get out of a row by row logic and use set based logic. Think of B as your select statement not a write. What you need is a self join on the table A.

Comment: Yea, that does make sense. I'll try that!  thanks

Comment: Use the windowing functions `over ... order by(date)` for your "next two rows".

Answer (score 0):

It's bad approach, but it's what you want:

```
declare @a table(mDate Date, MTime int, ACCCT int, Atm nVarChar(2), AC nVarChar(1), AMT int, Location nVarChar(50))
insert into @a(mDate, MTime, ACCCT, Atm, AC, AMT, Location)
select N'7/11/16',  1040, 5555,   '',    'C',   0,  'DUNKIN #3'          
union all
select N'7/11/16',  1105, 5555,   '#1',  'W',   -20,  ''          
union all
select N'7/11/16',  1105, 5555,   '',    'С',   0,  'ATM'          
union all
select N'7/11/16',  1105, 5555,   '',    'С',   0,  'DUNKIN #3'          
union all
select N'7/12/16',  2141, 5555,   '',    'С',   0,  'BP#9'          
union all
select N'7/19/16',  1025, 5555,   '#2',  'W',   -40,  ''          
union all
select N'7/19/16',  1025, 5555,   '',  'C',   0,  'ATM'          
union all
select N'7/19/16',  1025, 5555,   '',  'C',   0,  'SBUCKS #1'          
union all
select N'7/21/16',  2102, 5555,   '',  'C',   0,  ''          

declare @b table(mDate Date, MTime int, ACCCT int, Atm nVarChar(2), AC nVarChar(1), AMT int, mTran nVarChar(50), Location nVarChar(50))


declare @mDate Date, @MTime int, @ACCCT int, @Atm nVarChar(2), @AC nVarChar(1), @AMT int, @Location nVarChar(50)

declare @mDate2 Date, @MTime2 int, @ACCCT2 int, @Atm2 nVarChar(2), @AC2 nVarChar(1), @AMT2 int, @mTran2 nVarChar(50), @Location2 nVarChar(50)

declare @Fl int set @Fl = 0

DECLARE @Cur as CURSOR;

set @Cur = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
select mDate, MTime, ACCCT, Atm, AC, AMT, Location
from @a
order by mDate, MTime, AMT;

OPEN @Cur  

FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @mDate, @MTime, @ACCCT, @Atm, @AC, @AMT, @Location
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
if @Fl = 2 set @mTran2 = @Location
if @Fl = 1 
begin
    set @Location2 = @Location
    insert into @b (mDate, MTime, ACCCT, Atm, AC, AMT, mTran, Location)
    select @mDate2, @MTime2, @ACCCT2, @Atm2, @AC2, @AMT2, @mTran2, @Location2
end

if @Fl = 2 
    set @Fl = 1
else if @Fl = 1 set @Fl = 0

if @AC = 'W' 
begin
    set @Fl = 2
    set @mDate2 = @mDate
    set @MTime2 = @MTime
    set @ACCCT2 = @ACCCT
    set @Atm2 = @Atm
    set @AC2 = @AC
    set @AMT2 = @AMT
end

FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @mDate, @MTime, @ACCCT, @Atm, @AC, @AMT, @Location

END 

CLOSE @Cur;
DEALLOCATE @Cur;

select * from @b
```